# erroer while running pcl package

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following pcl/tutorial steps, but after i downloaded the source code example_voxelgrid.cpp and named it as example.cpp and than calling catkin_make from the root directory, it is showing:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl_conversions"
with any of the following names:
pcl_conversionsConfig.cmake
pcl_conversions-config.cmake
, even if i followed the full steps of step 4.1 im still getting error at cmake_error.
at starting of pcl/ros tutorial only im getting the errors, o man. im using ubuntu 14.04 with ros indigo, it has also said that for different version of ros the modification is deiiferent, i dont get that properly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235849/erroer-while-running-pcl-package./) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

reinstall the package and the dependencies, try again the tutorial steps. u'll get the result.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0